# Merge GWT standard theme resources into client bundle?

Tags: java, css, gwt

Is it possible to merge GWT standard theme resources into my own client bundle? In particular: the stylesheet and the images?

Right now, all the standard theme images and the standard.css file gets served as single files from the gwt/ subdir. That's, well, not exactly what the bundle stuff was thought for.

Comment: The question seems a bit difficult to understand. Please clarify what "merging" is and what you intend to achieve with the same.

Comment: Standard themes are not bundled into a predefined ClientBundle, but shipped into the war directory to be properly referenced in the choosen theme stylesheet (and the images sprites are copied as well). Anyway @SSR doubts still stand, please clarify a bit.

Comment: I'd like to have all the resources located beneath h ttp://server/<webAppUrl>/gwt/standard/ to be bundled in h ttp://server/<webAppUrl>/*.cache.html